# Error al mostrar mi lista de objetos en ASP.NET Core

Tags: json, asp.net-core, postman

estoy tratando de ingresar una lista de objetos en un datatable en ASP.NET Core ,estoy uniendo dos tablas , las tablas son  usuarios y rol , las cuales estoy sacando campos de ambas tablas , utilizo linq para unir los campos , me da una lista de objetos y esos objetos quiero que se agreguen en un datatable y poder mostrar la lista de objetos, al enviar en postman me da error
quiero que me iste los usuarios que tienen el mismo código sap , pero también que me muestre el nombre del rol y ese campo se encuentra en la tabla rol , me debolverá varios usuarios

este es mi repository

```
        public DataTable buscarUsuario(string cod_sap)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("listaUsuariosXrol");
            DataColumn usu_nom_ape = new DataColumn("nombre");
            DataColumn usu_usu = new DataColumn("usuario");
            DataColumn usu_cla = new DataColumn("clave");
            DataColumn usu_cor = new DataColumn("correo");
            DataColumn usu_cod_sap = new DataColumn("cod_sap");
            DataColumn usu_est = new DataColumn("estado");
            DataColumn usu_cod_rol = new DataColumn("rol");
            DataColumn rol_nom = new DataColumn("nombre_rol");

            dt.Columns.Add(usu_nom_ape);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_usu);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_cla);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_cor);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_cod_sap);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_est);
            dt.Columns.Add(usu_cod_rol);
            dt.Columns.Add(rol_nom);

            var usuario = (from usu in _quimpacContext.Usuarios
                           join r in _quimpacContext.Rol
                           on usu.usu_cod_rol equals r.rol_cod
                           where usu.usu_cod_sap.Equals(cod_sap)
                           select new
                           {
                               usu.usu_nom_ape,
                               usu.usu_usu,
                               usu.usu_cla,
                               usu.usu_cor,
                               usu.usu_cod_sap,
                               usu.usu_est,
                               usu.usu_cod_rol,
                               r.rol_nom
                           }).ToList();
            foreach (var item in usuario)
            {
                //creas una nueva row
                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                //asignas el dato a cada columna de la row
                row["nombre"] = item.usu_nom_ape;
                row["usuario"] = item.usu_usu;
                row["clave"] = item.usu_cla;
                row["correo"] = item.usu_cor;
                row["cod_sap"] = item.usu_cod_sap;
                row["estado"] = item.usu_est;
                row["rol"] = item.usu_cod_rol;
                row["nombre_rol"] = item.rol_nom;

                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            } 
                return dt;
        }
```

el erro que me da es el siguiente

```
System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported and should be avoided since they can lead to security issues. Path: $.Columns.DataType.
 ---> System.NotSupportedException: Serialization and deserialization of 'System.Type' instances are not supported and should be avoided since they can lead to security issues.
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.TypeConverter.Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Type value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWriteAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableConverter`1.OnWriteResume(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.IEnumerableDefaultConverter`2.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, TCollection value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonPropertyInfo`1.GetMemberAndWriteJson(Object obj, WriteStack& state, Utf8JsonWriter writer)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.Converters.ObjectDefaultConverter`1.OnTryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.TryWrite(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowNotSupportedException(WriteStack& state, NotSupportedException ex)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCore(Utf8JsonWriter writer, T& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1.WriteCoreAsObject(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Object value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteCore[TValue](JsonConverter jsonConverter, Utf8JsonWriter writer, TValue& value, JsonSerializerOptions options, WriteStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.WriteAsyncCore[TValue](Stream utf8Json, TValue value, Type inputType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonOutputFormatter.WriteResponseBodyAsync(OutputFormatterWriteContext context, Encoding selectedEncoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeResultAsync>g__Logged|21_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, IActionResult result)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResultFilterAsync>g__Awaited|29_0[TFilter,TFilterAsync](ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResultExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.ResultNext[TFilter,TFilterAsync](State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeResultFilters()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

quiero que me retorne lo siguiente

```
[
    {
        "usu_nom_ape": "Christian Espinoza ",
        "usu_usu": "cespinoza",
        "usu_cla": "123456",
        "usu_cor": "cespinoza@gmail.com",
        "usu_cod_sap": "0000105680",
        "usu_est": "1",
        "usu_cod_rol": 1,
        "usu_cod_cli": 1,
        "rol_nom": "Administrador"
    },
    {
        "usu_nom_ape": "Joel Torres",
        "usu_usu": "jtorre",
        "usu_cla": "123456",
        "usu_cor": "jtorres@gmail.com",
        "usu_cod_sap": "0000105680",
        "usu_est": "1",
        "usu_cod_rol": 35,
        "usu_cod_cli": 1,
        "rol_nom": "Vendedor"
    },
    {
        "usu_nom_ape": "Lucia Campos",
        "usu_usu": "clucia",
        "usu_cla": "123456",
        "usu_cor": "lulu@gmail.com",
        "usu_cod_sap": "0000105680",
        "usu_est": "1",
        "usu_cod_rol": 43,
        "usu_cod_cli": 1,
        "rol_nom": "Cliente"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los `DataTable` no son objetos serializables como JSON, en lugar de `DataTables` usa DTOs para almacenar tu información.

```
public class UsuarioDTO
{
    public string usu_nom_ape { get; set; }
    public string usu_usu { get; set; }
    public string usu_cla { get; set; }
    public string usu_cor { get; set; }
    public string usu_cod_sap { get; set; }
    public string usu_est { get; set; }
    public int usu_cod_rol { get; set; }
    public int usu_cod_cli { get; set; }
    public string rol_nom { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: No habrá otra opción? lo que quiero evitar es crear mas clases

Comment: Las clases son una de las mejores maneras de tener un sistema de tipos fuertemente tipado, lo cual se traduce en muchos beneficios a medida que un sistema de información va creciendo. El beneficio es inmensamente superior al costo en muchos casos. Si no te gustan las clases o desarrolla tu sistema en un lenguaje dinámico (de lo cual actualmente muchos se están alejando) o utiliza source generators que te generen esas clases que no quieres escribir en base a otra especificación (lo cual a la larga es mas trabajo)

Comment: Miralo de otra forma, la firma del método que devuelve un DataTable no dice nada sobre lo que puedes encontrar dentro de este. No hay ninguna garantía a nivel de lenguaje que lo que estas devolviendo efectivamente sea el resultado de una búsqueda de usuarios, en cambio el List<Usuario> como valor de retorno te está indicando precisamente que es lo que vas a obtener al llamar al método. Otra ventaja es mas fácil consumir una lista genérica que un Datatable result[i].usu_usu por ejemplo en lugar de la sintaxis mas verbosa del DataTable.

Comment: Además un error de tipeo en el nombre de una columna significa un error de sintaxis en tiempo de compilacion que lo ves mientras desarrollas en el caso de la clase versus un error en tiempo de ejecucion cuando tu sistema ya está corriendo posiblemente en producción antes de notar el error

Comment: Finalmente, el DataTable es igualmente una clase con bastante mas estado y por lo tanto mucho mas pesado que simplemente una List o Array de Usuarios. En tema de rendimiento las clases serán muy  superiores

Comment: Finalmente, el DataTable es igualmente una clase con bastante mas estado y por lo tanto mucho mas pesado que simplemente una List o Array de Usuarios. En tema de rendimiento las clases serán muy  superiores